# pg_restore input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql

Tags: postgresql, ansible, psql

I have a Ansible task that will load a db dump file in postgresql database.

```
name: Apply prod dump file
  become_user: postgres
  shell: "PGPASSWORD={{ db_password }} psql -h localhost -d {{ db_name }} -U {{ db_user }} -f {{ server_path }}/dump.sql"
  when: run_db_restore is defined and run_db_restore
  tags: django.restore
```

Problem is that the dump file contains CREATE ROLE and CREATE DATABASE section, and I don't want to do that because it will overwrite the process I'm creating with Ansible so I want to preform

`pg_restore --no-owner --data-only`

on a sql file, so I can only create tables and import data. Question is how can I fix

`psql -h localhost -d {{ db_name }} -U {{ db_user }} -f {{ server_path }}/dump.sql`

so I can import data in the database properly.

This function
`pg_restore --no-owner --data-only -U admin -d database dump.sql` is showing me

`pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that unless you edit the SQL file first, which is a challenging and error-prone task to do automatically.

I recommend that you change your procedure and use custom format dumps instead. Then you can restore them with `pg_restore` and only restore the parts you need.

Since you say that you have users in the dump, it appears that you created it with `pg_dumpall`. Don't do that if you don't want to have users in there.

Comment: Hey, thank for the answer, I'm not the one who is providing the dump file, but I've edited the sql file it self, so now everything is back to normal, also this command `--no-psqlrc` helped.